# Wireless roaming aggressiveness

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I was wondering if there was anyway to change the aggressiveness of wireless roaming between access points of the same SSID in ubuntu like there is in windows, I often times find that when I walk downstairs in my house that I have an awful wireless signal even though I'm basically next to an access point, so I have a feeling that its not switching access points when I move. I am running ubuntu 12.04 right now.

Answer (score 8):

My understanding is that the sensitivity to Access Point roaming, can be setup using iwconfig;

```
iwconfig wlan0 sens <value>
```

On modern cards, this parameter usually controls handover/roaming threshold,  the  lowest  signal  level  for  which  the hardware remains associated with  the  current  Access  Point.  When  the signal  level  goes below this threshold the card starts looking for a new/better Access Point. e.g.

```
iwconfig wlan0 sens -80
iwconfig wlan0 sens 2
```

([reference manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/iwconfig.8.html))

Comment: I get an "operation not supported" trying to set this.  may not work for all hardware?

Answer (score 0):

So I was wondering how you would get the currently set value.
I don't know if it is part of iwconfig output or some other command. Can't seem to find it.