# Change wifi roaming aggressiveness

Tags: wireless, network-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless roaming aggressiveness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137460/wireless-roaming-aggressiveness)

Is there any way to change roaming aggressiveness? We are having issues at our school with clients running 12.04 losing connection when hopping between two nearby AP using the same SSID