# Wireless roaming across multiple access points

Tags: networking, wireless, dhcp, static-ip

I have a medical application running on an intel edison device.
My normal daily routine takes me from home to school, then to work, and then back home. I may use 4 or 5 different access points in the day including my phone tethering and free hotspots.

Right now I am having difficulty because my work and school wireless is a static IP address, my home and phone tethering is DHCP, and open hotspots are open.

How do I configure my wireless settings to roam across all of them and pick the best wireless, including whether it is static or DHCP. Also, how can I have it validate that the connection works and that there is not a higher "preferred" connection available?

Comment: Are you using latest software on it (https://github.com/edison-fw/) or stuck with a stock image?

Answer (score 1):

Roaming depends on the platform.

All platforms will remember the TCP/IP settings for the SSID.

So auto connect/roaming is the only hurdle you have to cross.
This link should help you with your roaming tuning: https://askubuntu.com/a/182039/180773